# Prevent host OS (Debian) from talking to USB device before it has been passed through to VirtualBox guest

Tags: virtualbox, debian

I have Debian 11 as host OS and Windows 10 as guest OS.

In most cases USB pass through works well. For example when I pass through an USB pen drive to the guest.

But in rare cases it simply does not work. I then switch to a real Windows 10 PC and it works.

Yesterday I had such a case again. I wanted to update the [firmware](https://kaicolabs.com/firmware/) of a Kaico N64 HDMI adapter.

The firmware updater showed that the device is connected. But when I clicked on "Update" the progress bar simply didn't fill up. On a real Windows 10 PC it worked.

Because I had similar cases in the past I think there is no problem with this particular HDMI adapter. Instead I think it's a problem with VirtualBox.

I have an idea what the problem could be.

When I connect an USB device my host OS (Debian) talks to this device before it has been passed through. It initializes it or retrieves meta information (like storage size, device name and so on).

Now when I then pass trough the device and Windows talks to it, it is not untouched. Debian already sent commands to the device. So that could definitely be one reason for errors.

I know it's possible to save USB devices for automatic pass through in VirtualBox. But this doesn't mean Debian does not talk to them before. Maybe VirtualBox simply passes them through "very quickly". I cannot be sure.

Is it possible to prevent Debian from talking to a device before pass through?

Maybe I should pass through the USB PCIe host controller? Or is it possible to blacklist an USB device under Debian so it doesn't talk to it? Any ideas?